# Using the same data structure in multiple nodes

Tags: ros, data, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am designing a system which consists of multiple nodes. Among others there is a "gui" node for visualization and a "controls" node for controlling the whole application. During runtime I need to keep and update the information about a so called camera_unit for which I created a class CameraUnit (.h + .cpp files). The thing is I need to use this class both in "gui" and "controls" node, as the gui uses the info for visualization and the controls for other computations, but I do not want to duplicate the code. What are my options? I have thought of these:

**1. Duplicate the code** (Probably the worst option as I would have to always copy .h and .cpp file between nodes when editing them)

**2. Make the static library out of the CameraUnit class which would be linked to both "controls" and "gui" node** (That seems possible but I still feel there is a more elegant option)

**3. Merge "gui" and "controls" nodes to one node and make the gui run in a separate thread** (I would like to prevent this option as it would change my architecture)

Thank you for any advice!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221005/using-the-same-data-structure-in-multiple-nodes/) by [anoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23883/anoman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-11-16**:
Why don't you just include your CameraUnit.h in both nodes? #include <your_package/CameraUnit.h>

**Comment by [anoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23883/anoman/) on 2015-11-16**:
That would work but it would mean referencing the code from the different package and I thought this would not be really clean either. Or do you consider such an approach alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use a variant of number 2. Make the CameraUnit a class in a shared library. Basically with catkin, don't think about it and just use add_library. This change should just be 2-3 lines in your cmake file and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23883/anoman/) on 2015-11-16**:
It works, I just had to make a few more adjustments. You have to add lines

`INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src LIBRARIES name_of_your_lib`

in `catkin_packege()` in the node which builds the library to make it work. Is there any specific reason why to use SHARED and not STATIC library?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-16**:
static libraries would be linked into every dependent package. It probably doesn't matter for smaller projects. But you don't need to worry about it. catkin should do everything correctly here.